# Harmonic oscillator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, many-body, coherent-states

Given a single bosonic mode with frequency $\omega_0$, such that $\hat{H}=\hbar\omega_0(\frac{1}{2}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a})$ how should one show the equivalence between the coherent state path integral formulation of the partition function

$$Z=\int D(\bar{\psi},\psi) e^{-S(\bar{\psi},\psi)}, \qquad S(\bar{\psi},\psi)=\int_0^{\beta} \bar{\psi}(\tau) [ \partial_{\tau} + \hbar\omega_0 - \mu ] \psi(\tau) $$

and the Feynman path integral formulation

$$Z=\int dq(\tau) e^{-\int d\tau\frac{m}{2}(\dot{q}^2+\omega_0^2q^2)} ?$$

Comment: The variable $\mu$ is not defined in the problem statement.

Comment: @RichardMyers it’s the chemical potential